# How to write a generic Regex for the case below:

Tags: regex

So I have a scenario where I need to extract out all numbers from this string, now the problem that I am encountering is that there could be white-spaces between the commas or the actual number themselves. How can I write a generic `regex` to extract out only numbers. My current scenario looks like:

Test strings:

```
<classifier id="box-geometry" value="476,736,703,997" />
<classifier id="box-geometry" value="476,736,703, 997" />
<classifier id="box-geometry" value="476, 736, 703, 997" />
```

Attempted regex: `value="(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+)"`

Example: https://regex101.com/r/se0dwk/1/

As you can see, only the first string matches for all the numbers in their respective capturing groups.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Just add optional space before the digit: `\s*(\d+)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex pattern is missing optional whitespace.  Try including that:

```
value="(\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)"
```

Check the demo below.

### Demo

Comment: Thanks a tonne. The optional part was missing and I was not able to figure that out.

Comment: Have to wait for 10 minutes more before I can accept this answer. Some kind of a constraint enforced by S.O